# How do I gent my center div's width to utilize all available space when the left div has a fixed width and the right div doesn't?

Tags: html, css

I have the following situation, my left DIV contains my logo, which has a fixed width. My right DIV contains my menu, which does not have a fixed width. And finally, my center DIV contains a search field.

I would like my center DIV to use all the horizontal space that is left while the right DIV's width to be the minimum possible, so basically to have the menu's width. But since menu items can change, I can't set a fixed width for the right DIV.

Is there a nice CSS solution for this?

|--- Logo ---| |--- Search Bar ---| |--- Menu Items ---|

```
<div id="container">
    <h1 id="logo">
        <img src="logo.svg" alt="Logo">
    </h1>

    <div id="search">
        <input type="text" name="search">
    </div>

    <div id="menu">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Blog</a>
        <a href="#">Users</a>
        <a href="#">About Us</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are several but you should at least show us what efforts you have made in solving this **yourself**

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/b2g8j8ok/1/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `flex-box`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  margin: 10px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.logo img {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.container > * {
  flex: 0 1 auto
}
.logo {
  flex-grow: 0;
  background: red;
  margin: 0;
}
.search {
  background: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 10px;
}
.search input {
  width: 100%;
}
.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.menu a {
  flex: ;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="logo">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-200-150-8.jpg" alt="Logo">
    </h1>

  <div class="search">
    <input type="text" name="search">
  </div>

  <div class="menu">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Blog</a>
    <a href="#">Users</a>
    <a href="#">About Us</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**FlexBox - Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/rVJppB)

Answer (score 0):

I you don't want to use flexbox (due to the compatibility or other reasons), you can try with display property, and table-cell value:

```
 .row {
    display: table-row;
 }
 .left {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100px;
 }
 .center, right {
    display: table-cell;
 }
```

And html

```
 <div class="row">
     <div class="left"></div>
     <div class="center"></div>
     <div class="right"></div>
 </div>
```